# Regular Expression fails if newline is included

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a simple sentence from a string delimited with a # character.

```
str = "#text text text \n text#"
```

with this pattern

```
pattern = '#(.+)#'
```

now, the funny thing is that regular expression isn't matched when the string contains newline character

```
out = re.findall(pattern, str) # out contains empty []
```

but if I remove \n from string it works fine.Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Careful: regular expressions are greedy. A string like `"#text text \n text##"` will be matched with the second `#` included. Use Dima's solution to avoid that, or use the non-greedy variant: `'#(.+?)#'` with `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: @Evert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842633/python-regular-expression-fails-if-newline-included#comment19053779_13842679 ;)

Comment: @phant0m I don't get your point. That answer still has the greediness caveat.

Comment: @Evert How so? It can't match any `#`s in between the two delimiting `#`s, which essentially makes it non-greedy.

Comment: You know, I am glad I haven't had use for string matching yet. Regular expressions look like black magic to me.

Comment: @phant0m Have you tried? `>>> import re; re.findall('#(.+)#', "#text text \n text##", re.DOTALL)` results in `['text text \n text#']`, matching the second #.

Comment: @Evert I linked to this regex: `#([^#]+)#`. Sorry for the confusion. Nevermind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also pass the [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag, which makes the `.` match truly everything.

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Answer (score 6):

Use `re.DOTALL` if you want your `.` to match `newline` also: -

```
>>> out = re.findall('#(.+)#', my_str, re.DOTALL)
>>> out
['text text text \n text']
```

Also, it's not a good idea to use built-in names as your variable names. Use `my_str` instead of `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `"#([^#]+)#"`

It will match everything between the delimiters.

Comment: This does not have the same semantics. This will stop the match at the first `#`, instead of the last `#`, which may probably be what the OP intended. So +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag to your compile or match.